# mkSchemaDefinitions compilation error

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

Does someone know the what mkSchemaDefinitions accomplishes and how it accomplishes it? Lars calls it boilerplate code, but now that I'm having an issue with it I have no idea how to fix it. I'll attach the error message along with my relevant code.

```
 error:
    • No instance for (Schema.ToSchema MintParams)
        arising from a use of ‘Playground.Schema.endpointsToSchemas’
    • In the expression:
        Playground.Schema.endpointsToSchemas
          @((.\/) (Endpoint "mint" MintParams) (Endpoint "sell" SellParams))
      In an equation for ‘schemas’:
          schemas
            = Playground.Schema.endpointsToSchemas
                @((.\/) (Endpoint "mint" MintParams) (Endpoint "sell" SellParams))
    |
180 | mkSchemaDefinitions ''RoyaltySchema
```

```
type RoyaltySchema =
            Endpoint "mint" MintParams
        .\/ Endpoint "sell" SellParams
```

```
mkSchemaDefinitions ''RoyaltySchema
mkKnownCurrencies []
```

```
data MintParams = MintParams
    { name :: !TokenName
    , addr :: !Address
    } deriving (Generic, FromJSON, ToJSON, Show)
```

Comment: You should answer your own question rather than simply commenting that you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by adding `ToSchema` to the deriving statement

Comment: Would be good to add the actual statement change as code, not just describe it.